# Can not crawl website with Selenium in python (no errors but didn't work)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying scrawl comments from the link: http://www.phimmoi.net/phim/the-gioi-phep-mau-i1-6113/xem-phim.html. This is the code, I used:

```
find_comment = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='_3-8y _5nz1 clearfix']")
for i in find_comment:
    element_comment = i.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='_5mdd']")
    print(element_comment.text)
```

But nothing happened: no errors, no exceptions and nothing was printed.

Has the website lock crawled? If yes, please help me how to know.

Comment: The most likely scenario is `find_comment` is an empty list, and nothing is being iterated. Your first statement where you locate `find_comment` probably needs an updated selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on the website you posted are in an `iframe`, so you will need to switch to the `iframe` before you can locate the comments.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# first switch to the iframe
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@title, 'fb:comments')]")))

# then get comments
comments_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='_5mdd']/span")

# iterate the comments
for comment in comments_list:

    # print the comment text element -- the span which contains the commment text
    print(comment.text)
```

Comment: It's not working, can you check again? and why do you know the comments website in an iframe?

Comment: I inspected the web page and found the comments. Higher up in the DOM, you will see an `iframe` element. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I have tried your code and I don't have any error message.

Comment: That means `comments_list` is still coming back empty. I've modified my code to use XPath instead, see if this new selector strategy works for you.

Comment: I search in StackOverflow and have a solution to change iframe: `driver.switch_to.frame(f1c86504a69cf1c)`. Name of iframe in the comments are *f1c86504a69cf1c* but I have an error message: `NoSuchFrameException`

Comment: The `iframe` name is dynamic and probably changes every time on page load. The code I provided to switch to `iframe` is correct, because you said it did not throw any error earlier -- it would throw `NoSuchFrameException` if it were incorrect. The issue in the code was the selector used to find `comments_list`, which I have already updated.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the information `iframe` name is dynamic and probably changes every time on page load. I don't know that.

Comment: That's okay, that's why we are using the selector `//iframe[contains(@title, 'fb:comments')]` so that we can work around the dynamic name. This selector will always find the correct `iframe` to switch to.

Comment: But your update comments_list still empty. Don't have an error message and didn't print result.

Comment: Are you handling the captcha that appears on the website? I've been testing my code and I can't get to the website without entering captcha information. This won't really work for automation.

Comment: I did update my code with a different selector, and it is working, but you have to manually enter the captcha information in order to access the website.

Comment: I haven't seen any captcha. I have written a program auto click movie from category and everything okay, I test with auto 100 times and I can access a page movie which has comments and I don't need to enter captcha

Comment: Thank you so much, I have more experience to crawl a website. Have a nice day!

Comment: Glad it worked for you -- I was worried about the captcha, but it seems like you've figured that part out already.

Comment: Hi Christine, I'm a newbie with iframe when I used Selenium. Iframe can't autoload data when I click a button? I click button and comment I got just 10 first comments. I got back mainframe and came iframe again but comment I got just 10 comments. Can you explain why iframe not re-load

Comment: You will need to call the statement under `# first switch to the iframe` again to switch back into the `iframe`. If the `iframe` is not displaying new content then that may be an issue with the website itself and not with Selenium -- driver can only see what is in the HTML, which is not always accurate depiction of what is on the page.

Comment: I use ` first switch to the iframe` again and I have an error message : `Time out`. I changed `WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` to `WebDriverWait(browser, 200)` but I still get `Time out` message error.

Comment: The `iframe` display of new content. I think I wrong way to call `first switch to the iframe` again

Comment: I am not entirely sure what is happening here -- I know the code to switch to iframe works when you first get to the page, because we have both tested it. But I am not sure what the iframe looks like when it has new content -- if you can inspect the page and look at the HTML for the new iframe, that would help. It seems like the HTML may have changed, if the code is no longer locating the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_comment = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("._3-8y _5nz1 clearfix")
for i in read_more:
    element_comment = i.find_element_by_css_selector("._5mdd")
    print(element_comment.text)
```

**Reference:**
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector

Comment: thanks for your help, but your code is the same with my code (because selenium have more syntax to do this)